# Rpi - Cant use my /dev/hidraw0 as serial on my C# program

Tags: c#, usb, raspberry-pi, barcode-scanner, hid

I want to use my USB Bar Code Scanner, which is under `/dev/hidraw0` on my Raspi B+ device using C# code.

here is my current program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace USBSupp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("/dev/hidraw0", 115200, Parity.None, 20);
           sp.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: No such file or directory
at System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream.ThrowIOException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream..ctor (System.String portName, Int32 baudRate, Int32 dataBits, Parity parity, StopBits stopBits, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Handshake handshake, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Int32 readBufferSize, Int32 writeBufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream:.ctor (string,int,int,System.IO.Ports.Parity,System.IO.Ports.StopBits,bool,bool,System.IO.Ports.Handshake,int,int,int,int) at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Ports.SerialPort:Open ()
at USBSupp5.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: No such file or directory
at System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream.ThrowIOException () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream..ctor (System.String portName, Int32 baudRate, Int32 dataBits, Parity parity, StopBits stopBits, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Handshake handshake, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Int32 readBufferSize, Int32 writeBufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream:.ctor (string,int,int,System.IO.Ports.Parity,System.IO.Ports.StopBits,bool,bool,System.IO.Ports.Handshake,int,int,int,int) at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Ports.SerialPort:Open ()
at USBSupp5.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay never mind. With further research i saw that my barcode scanner is treated as a standard input device(keyboard) and the driver is already supported by my Raspi. So no need to use a program as the Barcode scanner's input is already interpreted correctly.

I am programming my Raspi via SSH through my laptop and the Barcode scanner was connected to my Raspi. And the reason why i didnt see the barcode scanner inputs was because via SSH the Standard input(STDIN) is my laptop, not the Raspi pheripherial devices (IE. USB PORTS)